# QQuiickWidgets within TabWidgets crashes when rendering OpenGL code

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml, qtquick2

`QQuickWidgets` embedded in `QTabWidget` container, crashes upon rendering custom OpenGL code, via QML, `QQuickItem` and `QSGNode`.

The crash or scene flickering happens when you click on the other tabs on the `QTabWidget` and return back to the rendering tab.

```
QQuickWidget* m_quickWidget = new QQuickWidget;


QTabWidget *tabs = new QTabWidget(this);

tabs->addTab(m_quickWidget,"TAB Rendering");
tabs->addTab(new QWidget(),"TAB 1");

m_quickWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView );
m_quickWidget->setSource(source);
setCentralWidget(tabs);
```

The above scenario runs peacefully without any problem when using `QQuickView`s:

```
QTabWidget *tabs = new QTabWidget(this);
QWidget* vw = QWidget::createWindowContainer(m_quickWidget);
tabs->addTab(vw,"TAB Rendering");
tabs->addTab(new QWidget(),"TAB 1");
```

[I have attached a qt project for emphasizing the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9n4Ne-yrKITaV8wZ2U4d0tUMkU/view?usp=sharing)

[back trace for more info](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9n4Ne-yrKITUGFjT1VxVTEwb3c/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Attaching a backtrace might help.

Comment: I have attached a backtrace

Answer (score 0):

Hi we have seen similar things including the black flickering, however 5.5 seems to have made that black flicker go away. Have you tried that?

Also, I would recommend that you post it on the Qt bug tracker so that someone from the Qt dev team can recreate and fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, yes I've tried it with Qt5.5 release candidate and unfortunately the issue still persists but with lesser symptomps. Also I've tried to post it on Qt-Bug tracker but with no serious reply from their side. However I would like to ask if were able to test my example against Qt5.5 and what were your impression?
Thanks for the help.